# Dell 2970 Server dual Opteron 2435's_Ubuntu OS incorrectly reporting CPU's

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, central-processing-unit, multi-core

The 2970 has BIOS version 4.2.1.
`lshw -c` processor gives me correct cpu information and core count = **12** cores.
`cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `lscpu` both give me **8** cores (*incorrect*).
OS = Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
I had to use the x86_64 version of the OS because of a 3rd party software requirement. 
Are there any SME's out there in forum land that might have insight into what's happening? I set grub to `acpi=off`. That had no effect. I'm just curious what I can do to get the kernel to register the right amount of cores?

Comment: It's my understanding that lshw -c processor is info read from whatever the machines' BIOS thinks is happenning. I'm running a dmidecode today to see if that gives me the same output. 
/proc/cpuinfo is what the linux kernel is reporting, and so is lscpu.

Comment: Nevermind I found my own answer.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/158555/how-many-maximum-cpus-does-ubuntu-support-by-default